# libsysstat 0.3.3 fails to compile

Tags: gcc, cmake, linux-from-scratch

### Problem

Following the description at [Beyond Linux From Scratch](http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/lxqt/libsysstat.html) libsysstat 0.3.3 fails to compile.

### Output

```
Scanning dependencies of target sysstat-qt5_automoc
[ 12%] Automatic moc for target sysstat-qt5
Generating moc source sysstat-qt5_automoc.dir/moc_basestat_YECEZINKJ3IAJR.cpp
Generating moc source sysstat-qt5_automoc.dir/moc_basestat_p_TOEWT4JHRJWB6U.cpp
Generating moc source sysstat-qt5_automoc.dir/moc_cpustat_2PPKBR4FZYU47U.cpp
Generating moc source sysstat-qt5_automoc.dir/moc_cpustat_p_DW2Z22GZ6EB36N.cpp
Generating moc source sysstat-qt5_automoc.dir/moc_memstat_G3LYEEDH6JN7I7.cpp
Generating moc source sysstat-qt5_automoc.dir/moc_memstat_p_G6GQ66YFWKKBLP.cpp
Generating moc source sysstat-qt5_automoc.dir/moc_netstat_3FYXG2JI64DH33.cpp
Generating moc source sysstat-qt5_automoc.dir/moc_netstat_p_AEQHBCUIMCHXXK.cpp
Generating moc compilation sysstat-qt5_automoc.cpp
[ 12%] Built target sysstat-qt5_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target sysstat-qt5
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sysstat-qt5.dir/version.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sysstat-qt5.dir/basestat.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sysstat-qt5.dir/cpustat.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sysstat-qt5.dir/memstat.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sysstat-qt5.dir/netstat.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sysstat-qt5.dir/sysstat-qt5_automoc.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libsysstat-qt5.so
*** Error in `/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000010257a0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x70b8b)[0x7fcaf381cb8b]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x76f16)[0x7fcaf3822f16]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN10hash_tableI15variable_hasher11xcallocatorED2Ev+0x7d)[0xb0007d]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x358e0)[0x7fcaf37e18e0]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3593a)[0x7fcaf37e193a]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z30diagnostic_action_after_outputP18diagnostic_context12diagnostic_t+0xc7)[0xf349c7]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z28diagnostic_report_diagnosticP18diagnostic_contextP15diagnostic_info+0x1ae)[0xf34c5e]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z14internal_errorPKcz+0xee)[0xf3615e]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1[0x8e3200]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x33000)[0x7fcaf37df000]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN10hash_tableI15variable_hasher11xcallocatorED2Ev+0x37)[0xb00037]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN3gcc12pass_managerC2EPNS_7contextE+0x35d)[0x83713d]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN3gcc7contextC2Ev+0x3d)[0x5e042d]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN6toplev4mainEiPPc+0x195)[0x543f05]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(main+0x27)[0x546627]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7fcaf37cc291]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_start+0x2a)[0x5466da]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0170c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562924                             /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
0190b000-0190c000 r--p 0130b000 08:06 562924                             /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
0190c000-01917000 rw-p 0130c000 08:06 562924                             /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
01917000-01a5f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
03a03000-03a56000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fcaecaa9000-7fcaecaeb000 r--p 00027000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaecaeb000-7fcaecb96000 r--p 00075000 08:06 562924                     /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
7fcaecb96000-7fcaf37ac000 r--p 00000000 08:06 557449                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fcaf37ac000-7fcaf3941000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf3941000-7fcaf3b40000 ---p 00195000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf3b40000-7fcaf3b44000 r--p 00194000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf3b44000-7fcaf3b46000 rw-p 00198000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf3b46000-7fcaf3b4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf3b4a000-7fcaf3b60000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf3b60000-7fcaf3d5f000 ---p 00016000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf3d5f000-7fcaf3d60000 r--p 00015000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf3d60000-7fcaf3d61000 rw-p 00016000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf3d61000-7fcaf3e64000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf3e64000-7fcaf4063000 ---p 00103000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4063000-7fcaf4064000 r--p 00102000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4064000-7fcaf4065000 rw-p 00103000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4065000-7fcaf41d6000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaf41d6000-7fcaf43d5000 ---p 00171000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaf43d5000-7fcaf43df000 r--p 00170000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaf43df000-7fcaf43e1000 rw-p 0017a000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaf43e1000-7fcaf43e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf43e5000-7fcaf43ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf43ff000-7fcaf45ff000 ---p 0001a000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf45ff000-7fcaf4600000 r--p 0001a000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf4600000-7fcaf4601000 rw-p 0001b000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf4601000-7fcaf4603000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4603000-7fcaf4803000 ---p 00002000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4803000-7fcaf4804000 r--p 00002000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4804000-7fcaf4805000 rw-p 00003000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4805000-7fcaf4879000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4879000-7fcaf4a78000 ---p 00074000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4a78000-7fcaf4a79000 r--p 00073000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4a79000-7fcaf4a7a000 rw-p 00074000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4a7a000-7fcaf4ad8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4ad8000-7fcaf4cd7000 ---p 0005e000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4cd7000-7fcaf4cd9000 r--p 0005d000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4cd9000-7fcaf4cda000 rw-p 0005f000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4cda000-7fcaf4cf1000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4cf1000-7fcaf4ef0000 ---p 00017000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4ef0000-7fcaf4ef1000 r--p 00016000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4ef1000-7fcaf4ef2000 rw-p 00017000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4ef2000-7fcaf4f15000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf4f2f000-7fcaf4f8c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4f91000-7fcaf4fbe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4fc7000-7fcaf4fcd000 r--p 00011000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf4fdc000-7fcaf4fe3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4fe3000-7fcaf4fe5000 r--p 00003000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4fe8000-7fcaf4feb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4feb000-7fcaf5011000 r--p 00000000 08:06 557127                     /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
7fcaf5011000-7fcaf5032000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf5032000-7fcaf50fb000 r--p 00000000 08:06 569727                     /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/gcc.mo
7fcaf50fb000-7fcaf5101000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf5102000-7fcaf5105000 r--p 00004000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf5105000-7fcaf5106000 r--p 00000000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf5106000-7fcaf5109000 r--p 00005000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf5109000-7fcaf510a000 r--p 00002000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf510a000-7fcaf510b000 r--p 00001000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf510b000-7fcaf510c000 r--p 00000000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf510c000-7fcaf510d000 r--p 00001000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf510e000-7fcaf5114000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf5114000-7fcaf5115000 r--p 00022000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf5115000-7fcaf5116000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf5116000-7fcaf5117000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff57c1b000-7fff57c3d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff57c81000-7fff57c83000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff57c83000-7fff57c85000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
*** Error in `/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000102578f ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x70b8b)[0x7fcaf381cb8b]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x76f16)[0x7fcaf3822f16]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7770e)[0x7fcaf382370e]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN10hash_tableI15variable_hasher11xcallocatorED2Ev+0x7d)[0xb0007d]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x358e0)[0x7fcaf37e18e0]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3593a)[0x7fcaf37e193a]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z30diagnostic_action_after_outputP18diagnostic_context12diagnostic_t+0xc7)[0xf349c7]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z28diagnostic_report_diagnosticP18diagnostic_contextP15diagnostic_info+0x1ae)[0xf34c5e]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z14internal_errorPKcz+0xee)[0xf3615e]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1[0x8e3200]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x33000)[0x7fcaf37df000]
/lib/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcf)[0x7fcaf37def9f]
/lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7fcaf37e03ca]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x70b90)[0x7fcaf381cb90]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x76f16)[0x7fcaf3822f16]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN10hash_tableI15variable_hasher11xcallocatorED2Ev+0x7d)[0xb0007d]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x358e0)[0x7fcaf37e18e0]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3593a)[0x7fcaf37e193a]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z30diagnostic_action_after_outputP18diagnostic_context12diagnostic_t+0xc7)[0xf349c7]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z28diagnostic_report_diagnosticP18diagnostic_contextP15diagnostic_info+0x1ae)[0xf34c5e]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_Z14internal_errorPKcz+0xee)[0xf3615e]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1[0x8e3200]
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x33000)[0x7fcaf37df000]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN10hash_tableI15variable_hasher11xcallocatorED2Ev+0x37)[0xb00037]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN3gcc12pass_managerC2EPNS_7contextE+0x35d)[0x83713d]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN3gcc7contextC2Ev+0x3d)[0x5e042d]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_ZN6toplev4mainEiPPc+0x195)[0x543f05]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(main+0x27)[0x546627]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7fcaf37cc291]
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1(_start+0x2a)[0x5466da]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0170c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562924                             /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
0190b000-0190c000 r--p 0130b000 08:06 562924                             /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
0190c000-01917000 rw-p 0130c000 08:06 562924                             /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
01917000-01a5f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
03a03000-03a56000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fcaec900000-7fcaec942000 r--p 00027000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaec942000-7fcaec99f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaec99f000-7fcaeca4a000 r--p 00075000 08:06 562924                     /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
7fcaeca68000-7fcaeca88000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaeca9c000-7fcaecaa9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaecaa9000-7fcaecaeb000 r--p 00027000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaecaeb000-7fcaecb96000 r--p 00075000 08:06 562924                     /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto1
7fcaecb96000-7fcaf37ac000 r--p 00000000 08:06 557449                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fcaf37ac000-7fcaf3941000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf3941000-7fcaf3b40000 ---p 00195000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf3b40000-7fcaf3b44000 r--p 00194000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf3b44000-7fcaf3b46000 rw-p 00198000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf3b46000-7fcaf3b4a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf3b4a000-7fcaf3b60000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf3b60000-7fcaf3d5f000 ---p 00016000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf3d5f000-7fcaf3d60000 r--p 00015000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf3d60000-7fcaf3d61000 rw-p 00016000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf3d61000-7fcaf3e64000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf3e64000-7fcaf4063000 ---p 00103000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4063000-7fcaf4064000 r--p 00102000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4064000-7fcaf4065000 rw-p 00103000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4065000-7fcaf41d6000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaf41d6000-7fcaf43d5000 ---p 00171000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaf43d5000-7fcaf43df000 r--p 00170000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaf43df000-7fcaf43e1000 rw-p 0017a000 08:06 562458                     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
7fcaf43e1000-7fcaf43e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf43e5000-7fcaf43ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf43ff000-7fcaf45ff000 ---p 0001a000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf45ff000-7fcaf4600000 r--p 0001a000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf4600000-7fcaf4601000 rw-p 0001b000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf4601000-7fcaf4603000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4603000-7fcaf4803000 ---p 00002000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4803000-7fcaf4804000 r--p 00002000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4804000-7fcaf4805000 rw-p 00003000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4805000-7fcaf4879000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4879000-7fcaf4a78000 ---p 00074000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4a78000-7fcaf4a79000 r--p 00073000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4a79000-7fcaf4a7a000 rw-p 00074000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4a7a000-7fcaf4ad8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4ad8000-7fcaf4cd7000 ---p 0005e000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4cd7000-7fcaf4cd9000 r--p 0005d000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4cd9000-7fcaf4cda000 rw-p 0005f000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4cda000-7fcaf4cf1000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4cf1000-7fcaf4ef0000 ---p 00017000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4ef0000-7fcaf4ef1000 r--p 00016000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4ef1000-7fcaf4ef2000 rw-p 00017000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4ef2000-7fcaf4f15000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf4f1a000-7fcaf4f20000 r--p 00011000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf4f2f000-7fcaf4f8c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4f91000-7fcaf4fbe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4fbe000-7fcaf4fbf000 r--p 00000000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf4fbf000-7fcaf4fc2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4fc2000-7fcaf4fc4000 r--p 00003000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4fc4000-7fcaf4fc5000 r--p 00001000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf4fc7000-7fcaf4fcd000 r--p 00011000 08:06 391727                     /lib/libc-2.24.so
7fcaf4fcd000-7fcaf4fd4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4fd4000-7fcaf4fd7000 r--p 00004000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf4fd7000-7fcaf4fd8000 r--p 00000000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf4fd8000-7fcaf4fdb000 r--p 00005000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf4fdb000-7fcaf4fdc000 r--p 00001000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf4fdc000-7fcaf4fe3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4fe3000-7fcaf4fe5000 r--p 00003000 08:06 391730                     /lib/libm-2.24.so
7fcaf4fe5000-7fcaf4fe6000 r--p 00002000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf4fe7000-7fcaf4feb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf4feb000-7fcaf5011000 r--p 00000000 08:06 557127                     /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo
7fcaf5011000-7fcaf5032000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf5032000-7fcaf50fb000 r--p 00000000 08:06 569727                     /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/gcc.mo
7fcaf50fb000-7fcaf5102000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf5102000-7fcaf5105000 r--p 00004000 08:06 561265                     /usr/lib/libmpfr.so.4.1.5
7fcaf5105000-7fcaf5106000 r--p 00000000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf5106000-7fcaf5109000 r--p 00005000 08:06 562919                     /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7fcaf5109000-7fcaf510a000 r--p 00002000 08:06 562154                     /usr/lib/libmpc.so.3.0.0
7fcaf510a000-7fcaf510b000 r--p 00001000 08:06 562510                     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7fcaf510b000-7fcaf510c000 r--p 00000000 08:06 391722                     /lib/libdl-2.24.so
7fcaf510c000-7fcaf510d000 r--p 00001000 08:06 391799                     /lib/libz.so.1.2.10
7fcaf510d000-7fcaf510e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf510f000-7fcaf5114000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fcaf5114000-7fcaf5115000 r--p 00022000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf5115000-7fcaf5116000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 391790                     /lib/ld-2.24.so
7fcaf5116000-7fcaf5117000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff57c1b000-7fff57c3d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff57c81000-7fff57c83000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff57c83000-7fff57c85000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

### Status

- It seems to be a problem with GNU Link Time Optimization (lto1) causing a segmentation fault
- GCC version is 6.3
- QT 5 is installed and working as expected

### Update

Is there any way to disable lto in CMake?

### Solution

What I did now to fix the error was rebuilding GCC 6.3 from source with --disable-lto flag. Then I had to edit the flags.cmake and link.txt file genarated by CMake to disable lto. Now it builds.

Comment: How is your question related to Qt and GCC? To disable lto you have to adjust the flags, not sure whether they are set inside a CMake lists or comes from a lfs script.

Comment: The error happens when linking against Qt and lto1 is part of GCC. I checked the CMake files and could not find anything related to lto.

Comment: Qt ok, but I won't remove GCC, because lto1 is the problem and it is part of GCC

Comment: which version of CMake are you using?

Comment: The CMake version is 3.7.4

Comment: could you try `set_target_properties(your_target PROPERTIES INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION OFF)` ?

Comment: I will try later, thank you :)

Comment: My first tries ended up with the same result. Having a look into to linker script generated by CMake it appends the -flto option. But even by removing it manually the linking process fails with the same error as above having problems with lto.

Comment: Yes, I believe because it's still some stuff is actually missing... [https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15939](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15939) .  
BTW, I do not understand how you got CMake 3.7.4 ... as far as I can see 3.7.2 is out.

Comment: Oh, it was a mistake - I meant 3.7.2 :D

Comment: BTW: even now with having no lto support in GCC enabled, some CMake packages add the lto flags to their flags.make and link.txt, other don't.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the LTO/IPO optimizations on or off by setting the *INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION* property ON or OFF.
Directly from the CMake documentation ([INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION.html)):

> **INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION**
>   Enable interprocedural optimization for a target.

and this should include the `lto` flag too.

To use it for a given target, you could have something like the following in the code:

```
set_target_properties(your_target PROPERTIES INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION OFF)
```

to turn it off; to turn it on you will do

```
set_target_properties(your_target PROPERTIES INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION ON)
```

Of course, the answer assumes that the enabled lto is the problem as you stated.